# How many panels of siding, 2 x 4's, and 1 x 2's would I need if all need to replace on a 16 x 80 mobile home?

Tags: siding

[image: mobile home with rotted siding]
Picture of the siding on mobile home.

Comment: Count the panels all the way around the MH that is the number of panels yiu will need.

Comment: 2x4s and 1x2s? What are we talking about here?

Comment: I downvoted your question because you are asking people to do arithmetic for you without explaining why you cannot do the arithmetic yourself

Comment: How many  siding panels , two by fours and one by twos are currently in the structure?

Comment: First answer. Boy do I feel stupid

Comment: Second answer. I was told by friend that because the siding is rotted so bad that all the 2x4's and 1x2's that hold up the panels of siding but I wasnt sure if that would mean that there would be 1 for each end of the siding or would there be a 2x4 in the middle also. And the 1x2's are the boards that are horizontal at the bottom. I assumed those boards were for skirting and the build of the trailer.  I know I'm not explaining all this very well but I'm doing my best without knowledge of how to build a house. I'm just trying to fix it. I had cancer and not Im trying to fix it with little money

Comment: Third answer. Dont be rude. I'm trying to figure out what is underneath all that rotted siding so I know what to buy. Besides, I suck at math. Jk.

Comment: Fourth Answer. There are 44 panels however I noticed a couple are smaller, like where the double windows are in my kitchen. I dont know how many 2x4s and 1x2s there are. Thats what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and your patience.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Two 80' walls and two 16' walls.  The perimeter is 80+80+16+16.  192?

It looks to be about 8' tall, so  192 x 8 = your square footage of siding.

If you think about 4-foot sections of wall, in 192' there are 48 four-foot sections.

Studs are either 24" (2 per 4' section = 96) or 16" (3 per 4' section or 144).   Sometimes 12" (192 obviously).

Comment: Joists? I think you mean *studs*. Would there be headers & footers too? (Not sure how mobile home framing is done)

Comment: @manassehkatz Quite right.  I don't know what OP will find when  he starts demo...